# URDF tutorial probolem

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Reader,

I have been trying to work through the tutorials URDF tutorials online and have had a problem with Rviz, It looks nothing like the [tutorial's example](http://     [www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)) and the are a few errors.

[Screenshot http://s21.postimg.org/41642i6l3/URDF_example.jpg](http://s21.postimg.org/41642i6l3/URDF_example.jpg)

Any suggestions as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67765/urdf-tutorial-probolem/) by [VeryNewToROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/5457/verynewtoros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to set the fixed frame to /base_link or /world if it exists.
Currently it is set to /map which does not exist.

As David Lu wrote in his comment expand the Global Options and double click on /map next to Fixed Frame. There you have to select /base_link. There should be no problem with the VM. The /map frame is the default for rviz, at least for me.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1